# Converting SVM hyperplane distance (response) to Likelihood

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, svm, pattern-recognition

I am trying to use SVM to train some image models. However SVM is not a probabilistic framework so it outputs distance between hyperplanes as a whole number.

[Platt](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=69187) converted the output of SVM to likelihood by using some optimisation function but I fail to understand that, does the method assumes one class has same probability I.E for binary classifier if all training sets are even and proportional, then for label 1 or -1 it occurs every time with 50% probability.

Secondly, in some papers I read that for binary SVM classifier they convert -1 and 1 label to range of 0 to 1 and compute the likelihood. But they do not mention anything about how to convert the SVM distance to probability.

Sorry for my english. I would welcome any suggestion and comment. Thank you.
[link to paper](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=69187)

Answer (score 2):

Well as far as I can tell that paper is proposing a mapping from the SVM output to a range of [0,1] using a sigmoid function.

From a simplified point of view, it would be something like Sigmoid(RAWSVM(X)) in [0,1], so there is not an explicit "weight" to the labels. The idea is that you take one label (let's say Y=+1) and then you take the output of the SVM and see how close is the prediction for that pattern to that label, if it is close then the sigmoid would give you a number close to 1, otherwise will give you a number close to 0. And hence you have a sense of probability.

> Secondly, in some papers I read that for binary SVM classifier they convert -1 and 1 label to range of 0 to 1 and compute the likelihood. But they do not mention anything about how to convert the SVM distance to probability.

Yes, you are correct and some implementations works in the realm of [0,1] instead of [-1,+1], some even maps the label to a factor depending on the value of C. In any case, that shouldn't affect the method proposed in the paper since they would map any range to [0,1]. Keep in mind that this "probabilistic" distribution is just a map from any range to [0,1] assuming uniformity. I am oversimplifying this but the effect is the same.

One last thing, that sigmoid map is not static but data-driven, which means that there would be some training using the dataset to parametrize the sigmoid to adjust it to the data. In other words, for two different datasets you would probably get two different mapping functions.